# How to configure OpenIdConnect and OAuth for Identity server?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am trying to configure the `OpenIdConnectOptions` and `OAuthOptions` in order to solve [an issue where custom claims are not mapped to the cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368522/how-to-pass-claims-mapping-options-to-identityserverjwt-in-asp-net-core-3-0-prev). I'm running the [ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview 5 react SPA template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0). Basically, the gist of the Identity configuration looks like this:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
   // These options are set
});

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(options => { 
   // These are not set
   options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("MyCustomClaim", "MyCustomClaim");
   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
});

services.Configure<OAuthOptions>(options => {
   // Neither are these
   options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("MyCustomClaim", "MyCustomClaim");
});
```

Now, from the logs I can verify that `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>` is executed, but neither `services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>` nor `services.Configure<OAuthOptions>` are executed at all. I was under the impression that Identity server basically is an OpenIdConnect implementation on top of an OAuth-server. So why is it that these services aren't used? How can I set these options for the Identity server?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you’re trying to add a federated identity provider then add a new authentication handler with the correctly configured OpenIdConnectOptions?

Comment: @Randy sorry if that wasn't clear from my question. Basically I wanted to know how  to set the `OpenIdConnectOptions` so that my claims got added to the access token provided by the server. In the end I solved the issue by using an IProfileService-implementation instead, so I haven't investigated this issue any further.